# CMS for User-Generated Content?

Tags: open-source, content-management-system, user-generated-content

I'm developing a user-generated content site.

Note it's not a blogging system, forum, wiki or any of those shrink wrapped things.  It'll have it's own specific forms and content niche, so I'd like the power to tweak everything basically.

The method of authenicating users will likely be 3rd-party ie open id, facebook, twitter, etc.  So the system would need to allow me to hook into another api for this purpose.

Anyone know a CMS built for user generated content like this?

Comment: This question is not really clear. You are asking for a CMS where you can tweak "everything", for a purpose that you have not stated, and you don't want a blog/forum/wiki/other for a reason you have not stated. So basically what do you want precisely?

Comment: Essentially I want a CMS where I can tweak the data structure and input anyway I like and let it take care of the familiar user registers-submits content-rates content use case for user generated content sites.

A blog/forum/wiki etc is not suitable for user generated content hence why I do not want cms's that address these areas.

Comment: Can you define why blogs/forums/wikis are 'not suitable for UGC'? Could you define what you *are* looking for?

Comment: because "It'll have it's own specific forms and content niche, so I'd like the power to tweak everything"

All the above have their own specific framework for interaction.  I would like a freeform alternative that lets me worry about user interaction while it provides for a method of authentication, storage, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen Agility CMS?  It has a UGC module that allows you to build custom content types for your user submissions and then allows you to hook the logins in with Facebook Connect or other provider.

It's based in ASP.NET

www.agilitycms.com

I happen to be with the company, so I can answer any questions you have :)

Comment: I've started building my own, but custom content types for user submissions was exactly what I was after, at least someone got it ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm confused... first you mention you're a developing a CMS then later you ask what premade solution works?

The closes you can get is drupal, well, even for pre-made system there is always something to "modify". Although I think James forgot to mention, Drupal has quite a steep learning curve and very long handbook so prepare yourself to take it slow and practice.

Also, it would be nice to know what programming language are you writing the web application? So we can provide more suggestions under that category.

Comment: I think the questioner needs to look at Drupal, and if it's not up to spec, come back and say why.  I think when he says "shrink wrapped things" he means things like phpBB and MediaWiki.

Comment: Agree; when the questioner says "a blogging system, forum, wiki", WordPress, phpBB and MediaWiki are the three things that come to mind - but all three are designed for a single purpose and have fairly narrow data models to support that single purpose. Drupal is about as general-purpose as it's possible for a CMS to be without devolving into a general-purpose framework.

Comment: correct guys re MediaWiki etc

Answer (score 1):

You've basically eliminated every CMS under the sun by insisting that no pre-made system could possibly handle the types of content you want...

But even so, I can still suggest two systems that might be configurable enough to do whatever it is that you need.

The first is [Drupal](http://drupal.org/). It's a CMS, written in PHP. It has a very very configurable and extendable system of content types (check out the [Content Creation Kit](http://drupal.org/project/cck)), and has a huge range of pre-written modules and plugins (even the CCK has its own [plugins](http://drupal.org/project/modules?filters=tid:88&solrsort=sort_title%20asc)).

Because of its flexibility, Drupal powers a huge range of sites - everything from single-author blogs, through community forums, up to http://whitehouse.gov. The Drupal site has a [case studies](http://drupal.org/cases) page which lists many different types of sites built on Drupal.

If Drupal isn't flexible enough for you, you probably need to stop thinking about a CMS and start thinking about a Web Framework - Wikipedia has a [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks) to help you find one in your preferred language. Personally, I've only used [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/); but [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org) and [Grails](http://www.grails.org/) are also popular.

Comment: I did not say 'types of content' I said 'specific forms and content niche'.  Of course the general medium is supported by every cms.  What I need is one that manages all the user and content input boilerplate stuff but yet gives me the power to choose the structure of the content.  Hence in end user terms the form they use to submit their content to the site.

Drupal is a relatively big learning curve due to it's general purpose nature so I'd go with this so long as there is not already a user generated content niche cms package out there.

Comment: just checked out the case studies page - they do not have a user generated content category and the closest category's examples (community portal site) only have user comments (on admin articles).  To me that is not user generated content.

Comment: Of course they don't have a 'user generated content' category - UGC doesn't refer to a type of content, it refers to where the content comes from. A blog system could be UGC, if the blog allowed random people to sign up and start blogging (eg - all of blogger.com is UGC). A forum is most definitely UGC.

Comment: Perhaps if you could tell us what UGC *is*, to you (rather than just telling us what it isn't) we could give better recommendations?

Comment: UGC - as in a general method for inputting user created content in a format of my choosing ie ignoring wiki/blogger/forum structures allowing instead a way for the site admin to define format of each UGC item.

Basically a multi-user CMS